# Use Lagrange Multipiers...

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use Lagrange multipliers to solve $ f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3 $ with the restriction $x^2 + y^2 = 1 $

I have that

$ 3x^2 = 2\lambda x$

$ 3 y^2 = 2\lambda y$

$ x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0 $

From the first equation I obtain $ x_1 = 0   ,   x_2=(2/3)\lambda $

From the second equation I obtain $ y_1 = 0   ,   y_2=(2/3)\lambda $

Using the third equation, $ y^2 = 1 - x^2 = 1 - 0 \Rightarrow y_3= \pm 1 $

or

$ y^2 = 1 - (2/3\lambda)^2 \Rightarrow y_4= \pm \sqrt{(5/9)\lambda ^2} $

It is not clear to me how to pick up the critic points and see the maximum and minimum values. $ (0,0), ((2/3)\lambda,(2/3)\lambda), (0,1), (0, -1), ((2/3)\lambda, \sqrt{(5/9)\lambda ^2}), (2/3,\sqrt{-(5/9)\lambda ^2}) $ seem ways to get points, but I don't know which ones to choose and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful. If your constraint equation is $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$, then the Lagrange equations are either

$$\nabla (f - \lambda g) = 0 \ \ \ \hbox{ or } \ \ \ \nabla (f + \lambda g) = 0$$

**not** $\nabla (\lambda f - \lambda g) = 0$ as you've written here.

---

Added: First note that $\lambda \neq 0$ as if it were, $x = y = 0$ which violates the constraint $g = 0$. Now from the two Lagrange equations, $\lambda = 3x/2 = 3y/2$ hence $x = y$. From the constraint $g$, it follows that

$$x = y = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: i corrected it (i beleive). But i still have the same doubt.

Comment: Ok. See my added piece above.

Comment: so the points would be $(1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2), (-1/\sqrt 2, -1/\sqrt 2)$ And evaluating $f((1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)) = 1/2\sqrt 2 $, which is a maximum value and$ f((-1/\sqrt 2,-1/\sqrt 2) = -1/2\sqrt 2 $ which is a minimum value.

Comment: Almost. Double check your calculation of $f$ at those two points.

Comment: $ 1/\sqrt 2 , - 1/\sqrt 2 $